# hidden tinymce editor not allowing to edit contents

Tags: tinymce, rich-text-editor

I am using Tinymce editor in my site
While loading page it is hidden (first step)
in second step i have displayed the textarea ..
hidden textarea is getting replaced with editor
but i am not able to edit the contents inside it.
Also in second step i want multiple editors

Below is code that i am using

```
tinymce.init({
selector: "textarea",
mode: "textareas",
theme: "modern",
plugins: [
    "advlist autolink lists link image charmap preview hr anchor pagebreak searchreplace wordcount visualblocks visualchars code fullscreen",
    "insertdatetime media nonbreaking save table contextmenu directionality emoticons template paste textcolor colorpicker textpattern",
],
toolbar1: "insertfile styleselect |  alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent  | print media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
image_advtab: true,
});
```